# Print a flag in as little lines as possible!

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, python

Just for fun, I wanted to see how little lines I could solve this problem in, using python. I managed to condense my code into 9 lines.

```
size = int(input("Size: "))
a = [x for x in range(size-2, -1, -1)] if size % 2 == 0 else [x for x 
in range(size-2, 0, -1)]
b, counter = a[::-1], 0
print("\n"+"\\"+"#"*size+"/") #top
for i in a[::2]: print("#"+" "*counter+"\\"+" "*i +"/"+ " "*counter+ 
"#"); counter += 1 
if size % 2 != 0: print("#"+" "*counter+"X"+ " "*counter+ "#")
counter = int((size-2)/2)
for i in b[::2]: print("#"+" "*counter+"/"+" "*i +"\\"+ " "*counter+ 
"#"); counter -= 1
print("/"+"#"*size+"\\"+"\n") #bottom
as you can probably tell by the output the code is meant to produce 
flags based on an integer from the user
```

with even number flags looking like this

```
\####/
#\  /#
# \/ #
# /\ #
#/  \#
/####\
```

and odd number flags looking like this, with the cross in the middle

```
\#####/
#\   /#
# \ / #
#  X  #
# / \ #
#/   \#
/#####\
```

I just wanted to see if anyone else could beat me, one of my classmates did it in four lines. Good luck :)

code with the least number of lines and bytes wins!

Comment: Hi, Since this is programming challenges, you need a winning criteria explicitly stated. The easiest would be code-golf and at the end of the problem add the the statement `The shortest code in bytes for each language wins`. Because in it's current state the community will most likely vote to close your problem.

Comment: Also limiting solutions to only one language is also a bad idea, maybe remove the python only requirement, someone is sure to answer in python anyway

Comment: Note that "fewest number of lines" is not a good winning criterion, as most languages can easily put their whole code in one line. Even in python you can simply write `exec"code"` to get everything in one line.

Comment: Sandbox can be a great place to bounce ideas off of: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/

Comment: This isn't an exact duplicate. This one only has # at the edge with spaces in the open areas while the other one is filled with #. It's not different enough for me cast a reopen vote though, especially while it's still restricted to python. Also it should say "least bytes." "lines and bytes" is two conflicting criteria.

Comment: @LevelRiverSt Could it be turned into a `tips` question?